# Spring Boot Docker : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I want to run my sql database and my spring boot application inside docker.

I've setup the docker compose as below .

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqldb
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0.21
    ports:
      - "33006:3306"
    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "Sympl"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD : "root"
    networks:
      - bridage_network


  merchant-service:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev"
    links:
      - mysqldb:mysqldb
    networks:
      - bridage_network

networks:
  bridage_network:
    driver: bridge
```

application-dev.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = mysql://mysqldb:3306/Sympl?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-while-idle = true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.time-between-eviction-runs-millis = 60000
# Specify the DBMS
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Spring boot start up logs

```
2021-12-04T16:22:42.017743220Z 
2021-12-04T16:22:42.017791429Z   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2021-12-04T16:22:42.017794762Z  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2021-12-04T16:22:42.017796804Z ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2021-12-04T16:22:42.017798595Z  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2021-12-04T16:22:42.017800179Z   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2021-12-04T16:22:42.017801804Z  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2021-12-04T16:22:42.018866429Z  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.3)
2021-12-04T16:22:42.018877179Z 
2021-12-04T16:22:42.117884304Z Starting MerchantsApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.13 on f0a304727913 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2021-12-04T16:22:42.118096887Z The following profiles are active: dev
2021-12-04T16:22:43.074667637Z Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-12-04T16:22:43.165314554Z Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 84 ms. Found 12 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-12-04T16:22:43.579244429Z Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8088 (http)
2021-12-04T16:22:43.588201429Z Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-04T16:22:43.588275763Z Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
2021-12-04T16:22:43.642654221Z Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-04T16:22:43.642679054Z Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1477 ms
2021-12-04T16:22:43.935904680Z Flyway Community Edition 7.7.3 by Redgate
2021-12-04T16:22:43.943746846Z HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090657709Z HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090813751Z java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090831043Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090839668Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090847001Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090856168Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090862918Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090869668Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:898)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090876501Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090883293Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090890793Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090897543Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090975251Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090987376Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.090994251Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091001168Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091007959Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091014543Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091021584Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091028334Z  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:54)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091035126Z  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:69)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091042751Z  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:508)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091049543Z  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:165)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091056209Z  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091063293Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091084168Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091093293Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091100501Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091107584Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091114626Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091121709Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091128626Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091135543Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091142793Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091149834Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091167334Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091186293Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091195543Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091203168Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091209918Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091216876Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091223751Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091231168Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091239376Z  at com.sympl.merchant.MerchantsApplication.main(MerchantsApplication.java:15)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091246209Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091263209Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091289209Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091300501Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091307168Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091324209Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091528459Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091546834Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091555459Z Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091563043Z 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091569959Z The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091577543Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091587084Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091594543Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091601959Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091608709Z  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091615418Z  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091636501Z  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091643834Z  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091650918Z  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091657668Z  at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:119)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091664334Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:842)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091710293Z  ... 44 common frames omitted
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091718043Z Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091725001Z  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091734126Z  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091741043Z  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091747709Z  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091758001Z  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091774168Z  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091780834Z  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091787543Z  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.091794251Z  ... 46 common frames omitted
2021-12-04T16:22:49.100847543Z Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.100933293Z Unable to obtain connection from database: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.100961501Z ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-12-04T16:22:49.100973959Z SQL State  : 08001
2021-12-04T16:22:49.100979793Z Error Code : 0
2021-12-04T16:22:49.101006209Z Message    : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.101021084Z 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.108711959Z Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-04T16:22:49.130412543Z 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.130488709Z 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.130497751Z Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150655626Z Application run failed
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150684626Z org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150689293Z Unable to obtain connection from database: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150691959Z ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150694334Z SQL State  : 08001
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150696418Z Error Code : 0
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150698584Z Message    : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150702751Z 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150707209Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150715334Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150718668Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150721001Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150723251Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150725543Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150727793Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150729959Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150732126Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150734334Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150737293Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150739584Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150742001Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150744251Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150761959Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150765501Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150767709Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150769876Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150772001Z  at com.sympl.merchant.MerchantsApplication.main(MerchantsApplication.java:15)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150774459Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150780376Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150782543Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150787043Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150791293Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150793459Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150795584Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150797751Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150799876Z Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150802043Z Unable to obtain connection from database: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150804293Z ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150806501Z SQL State  : 08001
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150808543Z Error Code : 0
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150810543Z Message    : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150812751Z 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150814751Z  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:68)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150816959Z  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:69)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150819876Z  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:508)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150822084Z  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:165)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150824459Z  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150827043Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150829376Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150835251Z  ... 26 common frames omitted
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150837376Z Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150839668Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150844251Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150850376Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150857626Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150861501Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150866126Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:898)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150870543Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150875876Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150881084Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150883251Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150885418Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150887543Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150894418Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150896751Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150898959Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150901084Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150903293Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150906001Z  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:54)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150909293Z  ... 32 common frames omitted
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150917293Z Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150921459Z 
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150924751Z The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150930084Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150932251Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150934543Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150942376Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150946626Z  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150953084Z  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150955418Z  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150957626Z  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150959876Z  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150962043Z  at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:119)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150964209Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:842)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150966376Z  ... 44 common frames omitted
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150968418Z Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150970584Z  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150972668Z  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150974793Z  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150976918Z  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150979043Z  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150981084Z  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150983209Z  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150988334Z  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
2021-12-04T16:22:49.150992126Z  ... 46 common frames omitted
```

I had a doubt that the user root might not has been created successfully , after I ssh using the blow command

> mysql -u root -proot -h localhost Sympl

I am new in docker and docker compose , but I have been stuck in this for like 10 hours.

I've tried many solution like not point to dev properties files an write spring datasource properties in the image  environment variables like this :

```
{
          "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/Sympl?useSSL=false",
           "spring.datasource.username" : "root",
           "spring.datasource.password" : "root",
           "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect",
           "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
         }'
```

but this solution has failed as well.